# how to instantiate a game object behind the game object while going forward

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate gameobject behind player's cube. How can i handle this and how can i check the area?

[here is expamle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksyMrVHVn3U)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the your gameobject forward set the position behind your gameobject of reference (I'll call ite snakeHead).

```
public GameObject go; //go to instatiate. Added in editor
public Transform snakeHead; //add in editor
private float behindDistance = 1; // 1m behind. You can try snakeHead.localScale.z/2

private void instantiateBehind() {
    GameObject myGo = GameObject.Instantiate(go);
    myGo.transform.position = snakeHead.position - (snakeHead.forward * behindDistance);
}
```

Also you can pass the pos in in the instantiate method itself with the `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);` overload. Check [Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Comment: It works, thank you a lot. If you are okay, is there any place that i can message you?

Comment: here is fine :)

Comment: So, how can i instantiate object group like in this game, should i use array? I cannot get algorithm.

Comment: you need to google it up and try something, if you get stuck you can once again write another question with a concrete doubt or problem :)

Comment: I thought about writing another. There are very few resources but thx.

Comment: just call the `GameObject.Instantiate` as many times as you need. If there is some logic that can automate that for you, give it a try